# Datepicker with date and time but only date is set to current (InfoPath)?

Tags: infopath

I have a datetime field on a list with default date set to current and I customize the form in InfoPath designer. I have a requirement that the current date should be set but the current time should be blank and the user has to manually enter it, how can I achieve this without custom code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one else replied, I got the answer here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010customization/thread/2bc46764-5379-4223-8db7-50de08548790